# How do I disable error propagation for a single group in a Celery canvas?

Tags: python, celery

Given two Tasks, one which does some work and another which does cleanup:

```
@app.task
def work():
    ...

@app.task
def cleanup():
    ...
```

I'd like to have the cleanup task run after a group of work tasks completes, regardless of whether one or more of the work tasks fails. I've gotten this to work by running `canvas.apply_async(propagate=False)`, but I really only want to turn off propagation for a single group:

```
work_group = group([work.s() for i in range(0, 10)], propagate=False)
work_and_cleanup = chain(work_group, cleanup)
```

But, that doesn't seem to work. How can I turn off propagation just for `work_group`?

Answer (score 0):

Chain only for successful task, add link error callback for calling clean up task.

```
work_and_cleanup.apply_async(link_error=cleanup.si())
```

Comment: This would certainly work but would be difficult to implement. This approach would require some type of book-keeping to prevent cleanup from indiscriminately deleting shared resources which in progress tasks might still need.

Comment: To set the propagate to False for each work task use method set.

Comment: for example:
work_group = group([work.s().set(propagate=False) for i in range(0, 10)])

Comment: I had tried that previously to no effect. Though, I'm using celery 3.1.8 (I recently discovered) so it could simply be a problem with this older version.

Comment: Chain only for successful task. If clean up should be the last task to execute, then have to use groups callback to fix this issue.